# How to reindex efficiently a DataFrame to fill holes in the index list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I have this DataFrame:

```
          value
L1 L2 L3       
11 21 31      1
      32      2
      34      3
   23 31      4
      33      5
      34      6
12 21 32      7
```

In this DataFrame, `(L1, L2)` is a tuple of IDs and `L3` is a week number. I want to add some rows in my DataFrame to have all possible week number for all tuples with a default value:

```
          value
L1 L2 L3       
11 21 31      1
      32      2
      33      0
      34      3
   23 31      4
      32      0
      33      5
      34      6
12 21 31      0
      32      7
      33      0
      34      0
```

In order to get this DataFrame, I get the list of the unique tuples `(L1,L2)` and the list of all the value of `L3` to create a new MultiIndex and reindex my DataFrame:

```
# Get all tuples (L1,L2)
l12_set = set(df.index.droplevel(2).tolist())

# Get all L3
l3_set = set(df.index.droplevel([0,1]).tolist())

index_array_l1 = np.array([], int)
index_array_l2 = np.array([], int)
index_array_l3 = np.array([], int)

# Creation of the index
for l1, l2 in l12_set:
    for l3 in l3_set:
        index_array_l1 = np.append(index_array_l1, l1)
        index_array_l2 = np.append(index_array_l2, l2)
        index_array_l3 = np.append(index_array_l3, l3)

index_array = np.array([index_array_l1, index_array_l2, index_array_l3])
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(index_array, names=['L1', 'L2', 'L3'])

df = df.reindex(multi_index, fill_value=0)
```

The problem is this method is very long a large DataFrame (millions of rows). I want to know if there is fast method already implemented in pandas library (or if there is a faster method).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `unstack` and `stack`

```
df.unstack().stack(dropna=False).fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[433]: 
          value
L1 L2 L3       
11 21 31      1
      32      2
      33      0
      34      3
   23 31      4
      32      0
      33      5
      34      6
12 21 31      0
      32      7
      33      0
      34      0
```

Comment: `df.unstack(fill_value=0).stack(dropna=False)`

Comment: Actually, I forgot.  You don't need the `dropna=False` if you use `fill_value=0`.  `df.unstack(fill_value=0).stack()`

Answer (score 2):

```
u = pd.unique([t[:2] for t in df.index.values])
l2 = df.index.levels[2]
df.reindex([t + (i,) for t in u for i in l2], fill_value=0)

          value
L1 L2 L3       
11 21 31      1
      32      2
      33      0
      34      3
   23 31      4
      32      0
      33      5
      34      6
12 21 31      0
      32      7
      33      0
      34      0
```

Comment: @jezrael fixed.